# Specifying external-format on ECL

Tags: common-lisp, ecl

How can I specify external-format (for example `(:crlf :|cp932|)`) on ECL?

I want to write string to file with some encoding.
So I type in my REPL like this:

```
(with-open-file (out "test.txt"
                 :direction :output
                 :external-format '(:crlf :|cp932|))
  (write-string "some string" out))
```

Then invoked debugger and it show this:

```
The function EXT:MAKE-ENCODING is undefined.
   [Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]
```

This is an wrong way...?
When the external-format is `:utf-8`, successfully written...

- ECL version -- 15.3.7
- OS -- Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3):

Based on [**§19.1.3. External formats**](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/new-manual/ch19.html#ansi.streams.formats) in the manual, it looks like the appropriate symbol is actually named "CP819" and is in the package named by "EXT", so you'd use **ext:cp819**, not **:|cp819|**.  You'd be able to use **(:crlf ext:cp819)**, e.g.:

```
(with-open-file (out "test.txt"
                 :direction :output
                 :external-format '(:crlf ext:cp932))
  (write-string "some string" out))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  
I'm sorry. Frankly, I read the manual and tried to use `(:crlf ext:cp932)`, but ECL returns `SIMPLE-ERROR` with a message `Cannot find the external symbol CP932 in #<"EXT" package>.`  
The reason why I use `:|cp932|` is, it is included in the return value of a function `ext:all-encodings`...

Comment: @t-sin Hmm, I'm not an ECL user myself, so I didn't have a way to test this.  This answer probably has the the same issue, then?  Any chance that `ext:|cp932|` (so lowercase, but in the package) is there? Or `ext::cp932`? Etc?  At any rate, this seems to be a discrepancy between the manual and the implementation, so you should probably get on the ECL mailing list/bug tracker/etc.

Comment: @joshua-taylor thanks for advising! Umm, it's means, perhaps, my ECL building way is wrong... I'll ask it in ECL community.

Comment: @t-sin BRPocock said that using `ext::cp932` worked;  did it work for you?

Comment: @joshua-taylor Sorry, I forgot to write... It did not work in my machine. My environment is not enough to build ECL maybe...

Answer (score 1):

Please fallback to ECL 15.2.21 or use git head - this is a bug introduced in 15.3.7